# GNU regular expression: Check every line for C10 or Z12

Tags: regex

I have a file with multiple lines. Every line starts with **C10** or **Z12**.

I'd like to check the whole file with gnu regex if there's a line not starting with **C10** or **Z12** (as shown in example in line 3).

```
C10     USE/0712015/004     831252      00248235    EUR 20071205             42.25  12137377-40-5                           USE/071205/004      Mika Muuu
Z12     USE/0712015/018     831252      01087484    EUR 20071405            400.00  8782400                             USE/071205/018      Bada Bing
        USE/0712015/021     831352      01017484    EUR 20271205            410.00  8782400-10-5                           USE/071405/017   Bubu
Z12     USE/0712015/091     131252      01087484    EUR 20171205            540.00  8782400-1                               USE/071205/018      Foo
C10     USE/0712015/008     232252      00248235    EUR 30071205             42.25  12137377-40-5                           USE/071205/004      Boo
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Hint: `grep -v` with a regex beginning with `^`.

Comment: You're great, thanks!

I think I found out that I have to add this to search every line:
/^(?!C10|Z12).*/m

Now I've noticed that I have to use "POSIX extended regular expressions"[Applicationdoku](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/regular_expressions)
So ?! wont work. Sorry, my bad!

How can I do that with POSIX extended regular expressions?

Comment: Sry, I forgott the @Aaron in the post above.

Comment: Got it: ^[^C][^1][^0]*|^[^Z][^1][^2]*

Answer (score 3):

You need to match lines starting with C10 or Z12 :

- `C10` will match C10
- `Z12` will match Z12
- `^` will match the start of the line
- `^C10` will match C10 at the start of the line
- `(C10|Z12)` will match C10 or Z12
- `^(C10|Z12)` will match C10 or Z12 at the start of the line

Now we can use grep to revert this match :  `grep -vE '^(C10|Z12)' file` will return lines not starting with C10 nor Z12.

If you don't have `grep` or another tool that can invert the result of a regex, you can still do that with the next few steps :

- `(?!pattern)` is a negative look-ahead : it matches only if the pattern doesn't
- `(?!C10|Z12)` matches anywhere that isn't followed by C10 nor Z12
- `^(?!C10|Z12)` matches the start of the lines that do not begin with C10 nor Z12
- `^(?!C10|Z12).*` matches full lines that do not start with C10 nor Z12

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier (and much understandable) to do it in two `grep` using extended support of PERL (`-P`). You have to use `-P` option because negative lookaheads are not supported by normal `grep`.

Also, whatever you are finding using negative lookahead, keep it within single quotes and not double quotes otherwise there will be `bash` error

```
grep -P '^(?!Z12)' input_file | grep -P '^(?!C10)'
```

You can also do it in single `grep` as

```
grep -P '^(?!Z12|C10)' input_file
```

Comment: Why not use alternation? `grep -P '^(?!C10|Z12)'` works fine too.

Comment: Oh, and about the bash error : it's bash history expansion that replaces `!...` tokens with commands from your history. Using single-quotes works just fine, but you can also disable it with `set +H`. More info on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark)

Comment: @Aaron I know..but usually I prefer to use multiple `greps`..It keeps the flow :- that is first you are rejecting one with one condition and whatever is left you are rejecting based on other condition..So I wrote it..

Comment: Nice ; I had no problem with your solution (even though I suppose it must be less efficient, but that's not always a concern), I just wanted to give some alternative :)

Comment: @Aaron thanks for your suggestion..There will not be much issue if the file is not too large..BTW I didn't even thought of a simpler solution as you mentioned in first one :- `'^(C10|Z12)'`..+1 for that

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few alternatives to negative look-ahead. In these, I assume a file named `input` contains your data.

- Successive filtering with `grep -v`:

  `grep -v '^C10' input | grep -v '^Z12'`
- Lines beginning with all spaces:

  `grep '^  *USE' input`
- Using awk:

  `awk '!/^(C10|Z12)/' input`